# Exception android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-runonuithread

When I try to run this code it gives my this error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` Here is the complete code:

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
    Button buttonX = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    buttonX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String message = editText.getText().toString();
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    Log_in.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override 
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                URL url = new URL(message);
                                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
                                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                                con.connect();
                                Log.d("URL Result", "con.getResponseCode() IS : " + con.getResponseCode());
                                if ((con.getResponseCode() >= 200) && (con.getResponseCode() <= 399)) {
                                    Log.d("URL Result", "Sucess");

                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GOOD!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Log_in.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } else
                                    Log.d("URL Result", "con.getResponseCode() IS : " + con.getResponseCode());
                            } catch (Exception e)

                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("URL Result", "fail");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}
```

I think I should use `AsyncTask` but I do not know how to use it on my current code, does someone have any idea how I should do this or my code is messed up and I should change it somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Well I don't think it is and that's why I asked the question, as I said I don't know how to use `Asynctask` to my code

Comment: Type AsynTask in google search you will get lot of tutorial...anyways for your case make the httpUrlconnection call in doInBackground method and pass the response code to onPostExecute method of asynctask...Inside onPostExecute based on response code display Toast or start an activity

Comment: I guess I could do that as well but now I solved my problem, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Thread() {
       public void run() {
             Log_in.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

you are spawning a thread just to make its run method run on the UI Thread. That's the **reason** why you are getting the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You have to use

```
 Log_in.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

only to make changes to the UI and to show your Toast

Comment: Well I tried what you said but I have to use `public void run` because if I don't an error occurs saying `invalid method declaration; return type required`. Moreover if I delete the run method below the runnable the urlconnection creates unhandled exception, would you be as kind to help me more please?

Comment: could you update your question or make a gist with the changes you made ?

Comment: I just commented the `new Thread {..}` and the `public void run {..}` above the runnable but the same error still occurs, sorry I am being handful but I can't understand how to do it

Comment: what I mean is something like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/16c0539e2562fcf58257)

Comment: Thank you very much for thoroughly explaining this, it works